# PDO SQL - Inserting dozens of fields

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Currently I have a page with a form with over 25+ fields, all posting to a single file that grabs the posts and stores them in a SQL database. I've found it extremely inefficient to assign variables to each post value, there has to be an eaiser solution.

Here is my example:

```html
/*Post Data*/
$val_1 = $_POST['val_1'];
$val_2 = $_POST['val_2'];
$val_3 = $_POST['val_3'];

$query = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO `database` (col_1, col_2, col_3) VALUES (:val_1, :val_2, :val_3)");
$query->execute([
    ':val_1'    => $val_1,
    ':val_2'    => $val_2,
    ':val_3'    => $val_3
]);
```

I feel like there has to be a way to accomplish this with a loop of some sort so that my queries aren't ridiculously long and messy like this would be.

Comment: You could use `str_repeat` with the count of `$_POST` to build the placeholders. Matching the value with the placeholder could get messy though..

Comment: you can use for each `$values = array(); foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ $values[':'.$key] = $value;}  $query->execute($values);`

Comment: Put the names into an array. Expand the array into a query. Bind vs. `$_POST`. No reason to make this complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple way:

```
$query = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO `database` (col_1, col_2, col_3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$query->execute($_POST);
```

With `str_repeat` you can repeat symbols as many times as you need, e.g:

```
$times = 20; // or sizeof($_POST);
$str = str_repeat('?,', $times);
$str = rtrim($str, ',');    // remove last `,`
```

Comment: This worked absolutely flawlessly. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. Will mark this as correct when it allows me to.